# sql convert from "record per month" to "record from/until"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, db2

We've a database that stores the values of employees per month (for example the part-time percentage):

```
+-----+------+-------+----------+
| emp | year | month | parttime |
+-----+------+-------+----------+
|   1 | 2015 |     1 |      100 |
|   1 | 2015 |     2 |      100 |
|   1 | 2015 |     3 |      100 |
|   1 | 2015 |     4 |      100 |
|   2 | 2015 |     1 |       80 |
|   2 | 2015 |     2 |      100 |
|   2 | 2015 |     3 |      100 |
|   2 | 2015 |     4 |       80 |
|   3 | 2015 |     1 |       60 |
|   3 | 2015 |     2 |       60 |
|   3 | 2015 |     3 |       80 |
|   3 | 2015 |     4 |      100 |
+-----+------+-------+----------+
```

for reporting purposes i need to display the values in a from/until form:

```
+-----+---------+---------+----------+
| emp |  from   |   to    | parttime |
+-----+---------+---------+----------+
|   1 | 2015.01 | 2015.04 |      100 |
|   2 | 2015.01 | 2015.01 |       80 |
|   2 | 2015.02 | 2015.03 |      100 |
|   2 | 2015.04 | 2015.04 |       80 |
|   3 | 2015.01 | 2015.02 |       60 |
|   3 | 2015.03 | 2015.03 |       80 |
|   3 | 2015.04 | 2015.04 |      100 |
+-----+---------+---------+----------+
```

my first attempt was to solve it with a simple min/max approach. but employee nr. 2 is a bit tricky with the recurrent value of 80.

any ideas/examples? Database is based on db/2 or microsoft.

thanks

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier if your db stored a full date instead of just the year/month (or at least an equivalent combined type).  Or if you could operate over the original base data:

```
SELECT emp, partTime, MIN(monthStart) AS monthStart, MAX(monthNext) AS monthEnd
FROM (SELECT emp, partTime,
             DATEADD(month, month - 1, DATEADD(year, year - 1, CAST('00010101' AS DATE))) AS monthStart,
             DATEADD(month, month, DATEADD(year, year - 1, CAST('00010101' AS DATE))) AS monthNext,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY year, month)  -
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp, partTime ORDER BY year, month) AS groupId
      FROM Monthly_Hours) AS Grouping
GROUP BY emp, partTime, groupId
ORDER BY emp, monthStart
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b9f0ed/55/0)</kbd>

Note that I'm specifically using an exclusive upper-bound on the range.  Date/time/timestamp types, like all positive, contiguous-range types (anything but an explicit integer count) should always be addressed in this fashion (it makes reasoning about and querying them much easier).

This answer is slightly deficient, in that missing months aren't directly reported (don't show as `0`) - there are ways to correct this, if necessary, although it takes more work.

Comment: i agree with you about storing data. but i'm not in control of the db, i just have to use whats given to me.
the good: we can ensure that there are no gaps in the data. So perfect solution for my problem!

Comment: I don't think this query works properly, as your own fiddle already shows (there is a record missing for emp 4 and parttime 80). Here is a fiddle with altered sample data to illustrate this more strongly: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35eaa/1.

Comment: @Thorsten - you're right, although this is mitigated by the fact that his source data has no gaps (which causes this problem).  Probably fixable, but not something I can deal with at the moment.

Comment: @Philipp - I made a slight mistake in my statement, which may generate errors in one case: if the first instance of a value is followed by the first instance of a second value, then the second instance of the first value.  This has been corrected.

Comment: @Thorsten - Error corrected (I'll be checking some of my related answers for this particular mistake when I get a better chance).

Answer (score 3):

This is called the Gaps and Islands problem. One quick solution for it:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(emp int, year int, month int, parttime int)

INSERT INTO @Employee
VALUES
(1, 2015, 1, 100),
(1, 2015, 2, 100),
(1, 2015, 3, 100),
(1, 2015, 4, 100),
(2, 2015, 1,  80),
(2, 2015, 2, 100),
(2, 2015, 3, 100),
(2, 2015, 4,  80),
(3, 2015, 1,  60),
(3, 2015, 2,  60),
(3, 2015, 3,  80),
(3, 2015, 4, 100)


;WITH cte
AS 
(
    SELECT *
        ,e.[month] - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.emp, e.[parttime]) AS Grp
    FROM @Employee e
)
SELECT 
    emp, 
    CAST([year] AS varchar(50)) + '.' + CAST(MIN([month])AS varchar(50)) AS [from],
    CAST([year] AS varchar(50)) + '.' + CAST(MAX([month])AS varchar(50)) AS [to],
    parttime 
FROM cte
GROUP BY emp, parttime, year, Grp
ORDER BY emp, [from]
```

Comment: Not resilient when the data loops years.  But yeah, gaps-and-islands.

Comment: I didn't know this is called Gaps and Islands. Thank you for pointing to that term. I agree with Clockwork-Muse that this should consider ranges that start in one year and end in another, but a fix for this would be easy. A great straight-forward solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this solution on Postgres given your sample data, but I'm almost certain that this will work on `DB2`. It might need some minor changes, not sure though.

To see how it works step by step you can start from executing the most inner block.

```
SELECT 
    emp, 
    (year||'.'||CASE WHEN length(min_month::text) = 1 THEN '0'||min_month::text ELSE min_month::text END) AS from, 
    (year||'.'||CASE WHEN length(max_month::text) = 1 THEN '0'||max_month::text ELSE max_month::text END) AS to, 
    parttime 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        emp,
        year,
        parttime,
        first_different,
        min(month) AS min_month,
        max(month) AS max_month 
    FROM( 
        SELECT 
            a.*,
            b.* 
        FROM(
            SELECT *
            FROM tablename 
            ) a,
            LATERAL 
            (
            SELECT 
                min(CASE WHEN a.parttime IS DISTINCT FROM b.parttime THEN b.month END) AS first_different
            FROM 
                tablename b 
            WHERE 
                a.emp = b.emp 
                AND a.year = b.year 
                AND a.month < b.month 
            ) b 
        ) foo 
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
    ORDER BY 1 
    ) goo 
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Result:

```
 emp |  from   |   to    | parttime 
-----+---------+---------+----------
   1 | 2015.01 | 2015.04 |      100
   2 | 2015.01 | 2015.01 |       80
   2 | 2015.02 | 2015.03 |      100
   2 | 2015.04 | 2015.04 |       80
   3 | 2015.01 | 2015.02 |       60
   3 | 2015.03 | 2015.03 |       80
   3 | 2015.04 | 2015.04 |      100
```

Comment: Please, don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  It's difficult or impossible to do `LEFT (OUTER) JOIN`s, and all too easy to forget a condition and turn it into a full Cartesian product.  Always explicitly list out joins and put as many relevant conditions as possible in the correlation.

Comment: this works very well on DB/2 too, thanks! first time use of "lateral" Join!

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it's called `LATERAL subquery` and it's a valid syntax @Philipp good to know it works :) Please consider voting on the answer.

Comment: I'm not complaining about the `LATERAL`, I'm complaining about the fact that you're not putting `JOIN` (or `CROSS JOIN`, in this case) in front of it.  Your answer is also not resilient in the case of looping years (specifically, it'll create a new record for identical `partTime` values).  It's also generally considered poor style to use column indices for grouping/ordering (that is, `ORDER BY 1, 2`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I agree, this can be rewritten using `x JOIN LATERAL`. Though, it requires `emp, year, month` to be put inside `SELECT` statement, adding `GROUP BY` and resolving ambiguity in outer block, thus increasing the code unnecessarily and selecting columns you never need outside. If you know what you are doing, you are paying attention to changes like column order inside `SELECT` list, so `ORDER BY _no_` saves space. I'm aware that some DBMS do not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Step one: Detect where a user or parttime change occurs (1 = change, 0 = same value as last line). You do this with the analytic function LAG.

Step two: Build groups based on the change flags with the analytic function  SUM.

Step three: Show one record per group with min and max year/month found in the group.

```
+-----+------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
| emp | year | month | parttime | step1 | step2 |
|     |      |       |          |  chg  |  grp  |
+-----+------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
|   1 | 2015 |     1 |      100 |     1 |     1 |
|   1 | 2015 |     2 |      100 |     0 |     1 |
|   1 | 2015 |     3 |      100 |     0 |     1 |
|   1 | 2015 |     4 |      100 |     0 |     1 |
|   2 | 2015 |     1 |       80 |     1 |     2 |
|   2 | 2015 |     2 |      100 |     1 |     3 |
|   2 | 2015 |     3 |      100 |     0 |     3 |
|   2 | 2015 |     4 |       80 |     1 |     4 |
|   3 | 2015 |     1 |       60 |     1 |     5 |
|   3 | 2015 |     2 |       60 |     0 |     5 |
|   3 | 2015 |     3 |       80 |     1 |     6 |
|   3 | 2015 |     4 |      100 |     1 |     7 |
+-----+------+-------+----------+-------+-------+
```

```
select
  emp,
  min(format(year, '0000') + '.' + format(month, '00')) as from_month,
  max(format(year, '0000') + '.' + format(month, '00')) as to_month,
  parttime
from
(
  select
    emp, year, month, parttime,
    sum(chg) over (order by emp, year, month) as grp
  from
  (
    select 
      emp, year, month, parttime, 
      case when lag(emp) over (order by emp, year, month) = emp 
           and lag(parttime) lag(emp) over (order by emp, year, month) = parttime 
        then 0
        else 1
      end as chg
    from mytable
  ) changes
) groups
group by grp, emp, parttime
order by grp;
```